# file Input Event type in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

So I have been using Angular and Typescript for a long time. I cannot seem to find out what the Type for an Input file is.

For example:

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)">

fileChangeEvent(e:?????){}
```

All examples purely just uses event without any type, and I am curious to know if such a type even exists.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

> The File interface provides information about files and allows
> JavaScript in a web page to access their content.

Try this

**component.html**

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event.target.files)">
```

**component.ts**

```
fileChangeEvent(e: File[]){
    fileName = e[0];
    fileType = fileName.type;
}
```

Comment: That could work since you pass in files with is Type File. 

But still begs the question what type is $event. 
Just weird that there is no clear answer.

Comment: It works, but it needs and adjustment, instead of `fileName = e.files[0];` it must be `const fileName = e[0].name;` thank you.

Comment: Also, it does not change a lot, but `e` won't be an array of `File`, but a `FileList`. The most noticeable difference is that `FileList` does not implement the Iterator protocol, so `for of` loop will not work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList

Comment: We used to do that (with type `FileList | readonly File[]`), but if we activate Ivy's strictTemplates options, it errors on these lines: `TS2339: Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'` and `TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'`. So either we use the ugly `$any($event.target).files`, or we are back to type `$event`.

Comment: IF you try $event.target?.files is it working?

Answer (score 58):

For Angular 10 strict-type mode, we need to mention type in parameters.
You can follow this way to achieve file-list from file input event

```
// HTML
<input type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)">

// TS
uploadFile(event: Event) {
    const element = event.currentTarget as HTMLInputElement;
    let fileList: FileList | null = element.files;
    if (fileList) {
      console.log("FileUpload -> files", fileList);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Please share your feedback.

Comment: Be careful with event.currentTarget. It contains an element to which the attached is handler but not an element which triggered the event.

Comment: As the above commenter said, should be event.target See [Comparison of Event Targets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets).

Comment: how do you avoid the unresponsive change event if you select the same file twice?

Answer (score 34):

Angular 10 and above:

**component.html**

```
    <input type="file" (change)="upload($event)">
```

**component.ts**

```
  upload(event: Event) {
      const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
      const files = target.files as FileList;
      console.log(files);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the type does not exist, manually build what you expect

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)">

fileChangeEvent(e: Event & {target: HTMLInputElement & { files: FileList | null}}){}
```

Answer (score -1):

The type is **`Event`**

```
fileChangeEvent(e: Event){}
```

Comment: Problem with using Event is. if you type e.target it only has 3 functions on that Type.

AddEventListener, DispatchEvent, RemoveEventListener. 
So technically the type is not correct.

Comment: Depends on what you import I guess, VSC auto-suggested the right "Event" type right away in my case

Answer (score -6):

One line statement to get the file Type:

```js
fileInput: any
fetchFileType($event);

fetchFileType(fileInput: any) {
  fileName = this.fileInput.target.files[0];
  fileType = fileName.type;
}
```

Comment: any should really not be used if absolutely necessary. Plus That is exactly what the question was about. The Type.