# angular1 (Change) not working on multiple file select

Tags: angularjs

I want to call a function from controller whenever the input file selection changed or a user selected a file. but it's not working.

```
     <input id="selected-images" accept="image/*" type="file" (change)="upload.selectFile($event)" multiple />
  <button id="select-image" class="btn btn-primary-alt " style="border-radius: 8px; padding: 15px 25px;" type="button" onclick="$('#selected-images').click();">Upload from Storage</button>
```

This is the function selectFile from controller:

```
        $scope.selectFile = function (event) {
            console.log('awdawdawdawdaw');
            vm.selectedFiles = event.target.files;

              console.log('====================================');
              console.log('this is the selected file from selectFile function');
              console.log(vm.selectedFiles);
              console.log('====================================');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you nest the `selectFile(event)` function in an object named `upload`, but adding the following code in the typescript code of the component definitely gets called and the file list gets logged:

```
upload = {
    selectFile: (event) => {
      const element = event.currentTarget as HTMLInputElement;
      let fileList: FileList | null = element.files;
      if (fileList) {
        console.log(fileList);
      }
    }
  }
```

Please also take a look here: [file Input Event type in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59208257/file-input-event-type-in-angular)

Comment: Thank you for you response, will try this solution and get back :D

Comment: Hi Fabian, still not working on my end :(, were not using typescript in our project, and the upload name is the alias of controller that I'm using.

Comment: I included the controller code on the details :D

Comment: are you using angularjs and not angular? If yes, I suggest to adjust the tags assigned to this. From my point of view it could still be the issue, that you are calling `upload.selectFile($event)` and not `selectFile($event)` as I am not sure where this `upload` object should be coming from.